# Rails: use another .env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running a mastodon server with two instances on the same server.

Mastodon is basically a rails app and has the command line tool called tootctl.

Normally you use it like so:

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/tootctl accounts modify alice --role Owner`

This uses the default env file .env.production that was created when installing the first instance.

But now I need to manage the second instance for which I need to use the second env file .env.production.de

Question: How do I tell rails to use another .env file than the default one?

I would need something like
`RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_ENV_FILE=.env.production.de bin/tootctl accounts modify alice --role Owner` .

Answer (score 2):

For each of the Rails apps you can use **Option Three: Use a local_env.yml File** as found in this article: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

So something like:

The local_env.yml File

Create a file config/local_env.yml:

```
# Rename this file to local_env.yml
# Add account settings and API keys here.
# This file should be listed in .gitignore to keep your settings secret!
# Each entry gets set as a local environment variable.
# This file overrides ENV variables in the Unix shell.
# For example, setting:
# GMAIL_USERNAME: 'Your_Gmail_Username'
# makes 'Your_Gmail_Username' available as ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]
GMAIL_USERNAME: 'Your_Gmail_Username'
```

Set .gitignore
If you have created a git repository for your application, your application root directory should contain a file named .gitignore (it is a hidden file). **Be sure your .gitignore file contains:**

```
/config/local_env.yml
```

This prevents the config/local_env.yml file from being checked into a git repository and made available for others to see.

**Rails Application Configuration File**

Rails provides the config/application.rb file for specifying settings for various Rails components. We want to set our environment variables before any other settings. Rails provides a config.before_configuration method to do so.

Find the following code at the end of the config/application.rb file:

```
#Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

and add this code after it:

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

The code opens the config/local_env.yml file, reads each key/value pair, and sets environment variables.

The code only runs if the file exists. If the file exists, the code overrides ENV variables set in the Unix shell.

This way each Rails app has its own ENV variables but you can access them all with the same `ENV["SOME_KEY"]`

**Important**: Understand that since these files are in .ignore they won't get backed up to version control. But also if you are pushing to your production sever elsewhere they won't get copied over, you'd have to do that manually. And if you are storing passwords or API keys the file is not encrypted in any way so it is not secure if someone gains access to your server. I'm not sure how services like Heroku store their ENV variables that you can set. Probably encrypted in your Rails install using your profile. You will probably want to research that if you choose to go this route.

Comment: Make sure this is after the line for `Dotenv::Railtie.load` [Here](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/main/config/application.rb#L48) otherwise the .env files will override this configuration as they also hook into `before_configuration` [Here](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/blob/master/lib/dotenv/rails.rb#L41)

Comment: Thank you, I believe the article linked to is referring to an old version of Rails.

Comment: The real problem is the OP is running an OOTB application. Other changes could be made as well like adding `Dotenv.overload('.env.production.de')` but these options cannot be passed directly through the CLI as requested in the post.

Comment: That was their example, but am I wrong to think the two apps are living in different directories? Or are they looking to spin up two instances of the same app from the same code directory? And if `RAILS_ENV=production` references the file in `app/config/environments` could they make a file called `app/config/environments/production_2` can use `RAILS_ENV=production_2` to reference that file? I'm just guessing at this point but it's the way I learn. LOL

Comment: Thanks @Beartech for this elaborate answer. The plan was to use the very same app, i.e. same code directory.

Comment: @engineersmnky FYI: mastodon creator said in 2018 this is possible, [see here](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/issues/7972), but in 2023 I am stuck with this problem here. Do you guys still think this is possible?

Comment: @archygriswald are you running these as separate applications in different directories? If so then you don't need to do anything special, you just need separate .env files in each application. If you are trying do all of this through 1 application then there are issues because what the "creator" is saying is in regards to overriding specific environment variables not the entire .env load process. Additionally they are referencing running multiple applications on different ports. At least that is how I am understanding it

Comment: @engineersmnky it would be "all of this through one application". But I see now that these "issues" are not easily overcome - and my Rails skills are far too weak. Thank you very much for your insight.

Comment: @archygriswald why not just copy the install to a second directory and run the second install separately? Just have to run it on a different port. If they are going to be public facing you'd need to route each one to the appropriate port but that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @Beartech Yes, thats exactly what I did yesterday. I never used Ruby/Rails before, and I was too eager to reuse as much code as possible. Now I am running 2 apps in separate directories and it works great. Thank you again, you helped me understand the underlying mechanics